# Which API key do I need to implement Google Maps/Street View?

Tags: google, html, api

First time implementing Google Maps/Street View, side-by-side into a webpage.

Which API Key do I need please?

Source Link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple

See below, it ask for a personal API key, once again which API key do I need?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View side-by-side</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map, #pano {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 45%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="pano"></div>
    <script>

function initialize() {
  var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14
  });
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&signed_in=true&callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will find everything you need to know about the API key on this Google page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Simply scroll down and hit the `Get Key` button, accept the terms and you'll be ready.

Comment: Thx Zoon, I now have the correct API key.

Comment: @BrendanLizzo Perfect, I'm happy to hear it. If you feel your question has been answered, please remember to mark the answer that solved your question by hitting the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

CLick below 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&signed_in=true&callback=initialize">

On the "Your API Key" Then Developers console will open,ON the top You will see "Enable and Mange API's" Then fill the form you will find your API KEy  [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/start)